# Strategies to increasing the maintainability of assertions in code

Tags: design-patterns, testing, c, compiler, assertions

## Background

I am writing a compiler for a custom language for a school project and it is going really well for me.

If I where to start all over from scratch I would have done many software architecture things different, but right now I do not have time or motivation for a complete rewrite so I will focus on just finishing this project instead.

There is one thing in my code that I want to refactor right now and it is how I organize my assertions.

I am writing this compiler in the *C* using *flex* and *bison* to generate my lexer and parser. The code in this project is not very clean and quite messy but I am not ashamed of it (compilers are quite complex and this is my first try). But I have added assertions in the code to make bugs get spotted in time and easier to track down.

## The problem

The problem I am having with `assert` in this project is that there is simply too much to check for.

Here is an example from a function that adds the function parameters to the symbol table when compiling a function definition:

```
static void add_function_params_to_symbols(struct context *con, 
        const struct ast_op *function_def) {
    struct ast *child = function_def->childs[0];
    assert(child);
    assert(child->type == SYN_DECLARATOR);
    assert(child->val_type == AST_OP);
    child = child->val.op.childs[1];
    assert(child);
    assert(child->type == SYN_FUNCTION);
    assert(child->val_type == AST_OP);
    child = child->val.op.childs[1];
    assert(child);
    assert(child->type == SYN_PARAMETER_LIST);
    assert(child->val_type == AST_OP);
    parameter_list_to_symbols(con, &child->val.op);
}
```

This function has **three times** as many assertions as code statements!

This is quite an extreme example because this function has to go down three levels to the bottom of the tree in order to find the `PARAMETER_LIST` which it then passes to `parameter_list_to_symbols` which adds the parameters to the symbol table.

The parse tree for a function definition in my compiler looks somewhat like this:

```
FUNCTION_DEF
 DECLARATOR
  IDENTIFIER [function_name]
  FUNCTION
   [return type]
   PARAMETER_LIST
    [declarators containing type and name for each parameter]
    [...]
 FUNCTION_BODY
  [statements in function body]
  [...]
```

There are four things for me to test for each node that I use throughout the program.

1. `assert(node)` to check that the node is not `NULL`
2. `assert(node->type == SYN_FOOBAR)` to check that the node is of the expected type (like `SYN_EXPRESSION` or `SYN_VARIABLE`).
3. `assert(child->val_type == AST_OP)` to check that the node has the right kind of `union` value. Nodes can also contain other values. For example in nodes that store a string value `child->val_type` would be equal to `AST_STRING`. `AST_OP` means that the node is an *operator* node which is a node that has children.
4. I should probably also assert that each node has the right number of children with `assert(child->val.op.n_childs == XXX)` but I have not done that in this code example because it is already so full of assertions and asserting this too does not seem to add much value.

I have probably written hundreds of assertions like this in my code and it feels like this is getting quite hard to maintain but I am not sure how I should reorganize it.

## The question

Am I "over asserting" stuff in my code? What things should I assert and what things can I assume are *OK*?

How should I structure my assertions to make them easier to maintain?

If you have more tips on using assertions and similar tests in code please mention them in your answer.

Comment: Assertions should only be used to find programming errors. The question to ask yourself is: If any of those assertions fails, does that indicate I made an error in my compiler or does it fail because I am trying to compile some strange source file that my compiler should be able to handle gracefully. Assertions are only suitable for the first of those.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I am using assertions to find bugs not to check input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Am I "over asserting" stuff in my code?

No.  You have even admitted that you know of at least one little thing that you could have asserted but you haven't, so you are not asserting enough.

> What things should I assert and what things can I assume are OK?

Assert **everything**.  Assume **nothing**.

> How should I structure my assertions to make them easier to maintain?

One technique that I use is that I have special assertion functions which are meant to be invoked from within assertions, to perform many assertions together. They always begin with the prefix 'assert', and they always return true, so that if none of the contained assertions fails, then the calling assertion will succeed.  So, for example:

```
boolean assertNodeOfTypeXYZIsOkay( Node* pNode )
{
    assert( pNode != NULL );
    assert( pNode->something_irrelevant_to_node_type );
    assert( pNode->type == NODE_TYPE_XYZ );
    assert( pNode->one_thing_relevant_to_node_type );
    assert( pNode->another_thing_relevant_to_node_type );
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Which is invoked as follows:

```
assert( assertNodeOfTypeXYZIsOkay( pNode ) );
```

This allows me to get many assertions out of the way, while at the same time enjoying the benefit of conditional compilation: if assertions are disabled, `assertNodeIsOkay()` will not only be empty, but it will not even be invoked.

> If you have more tips on using assertions and similar tests in code please mention it in your answer.

Having more assertions than actual code is kind of rare, but it is not unheard of. It really depends on what you are doing, and it appears that your particular kind of project calls for this situation to happen.  That's fine.

Once your compiler matures and becomes stable, it will stop failing every once in a while due to oddly formulated input text. When that happens, you will be able to have a release build of your compiler on which assertions are disabled, for maximum performance. With that in mind, you should be applying assertions as liberally as you can, because they practically cost nothing.

Assertions are an excellent documentation tool, since a) comments are not enforceable by the compiler, and b) no comment ever was, or will ever be, as unambiguous as a piece of code stipulating the same thing.

Assertions *reduce* the complexity of your code, in contrast to virtually any other statement that you can use, which in fact *increases* the complexity of your code.

Assertions help build systems that, in the event of an error, can tell you what is wrong with themselves.  That, right there, is priceless.

Assertions are the best thing since sliced bread.

The question you should always be asking is not "should I assert this?" but "is there anything I forgot to assert?"

Comment: For a lengthier discussion of some of the points that I made above, see this blog post of mine: [michael.gr - Assertions and Testing](http://blog.michael.gr/2014/09/assertions-and-testing.html)

Comment: Very good tip refactoring the assertion code into seperate functions. I did that and now everything is so much cleaner. I have no idea why I did not think of that before. The intention of `assert(is_valid_declaration(node))` is also so much more clearer than the gibberish I had before!

Comment: The idea behind calling these functions `assert_...` instead of `is_valid_...` is to make it evident that they are not meant to be invoked as part of regular user input validation.  Because if you mistakenly invoke one of these functions for validation, then on the debug build you will get an assertion failure, (that's not what you want to happen as part of validation,) while on the release build everything will pass, no matter how invalid.

Comment: In some cases you may have both `assert_xyz()` and `is_valid_xyz()` side by side, and `assert_xyz()` may be implemented as `assert( is_valid_xyz() );` but you need to be careful not to confuse the two.  Thus, the distinct naming convention.